# Strip part of a string in a column using pyspark

Tags: string, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to strip a part of a string in a column using .withColumn

This is how the values are in the column:

```
df1["column1"] = ["Temp 1 (gen. comb.)", "Temp 1", "Temp 2 (gen. comb.)", "Temp 2","Temp 3 (gen. comb.)", "Temp 3"]
```

I want to strip the value (gen. comb.) from the column

**Code I tried in PySpark:**

```
result_df = res.withColumn('c_model_detail', F.regexp_replace('column1', '(gen. comb.)', ''))
```

**But when i try the above the resultant column looks like this:**

```
 result_df["column1"] = ["Temp 1 ()", "Temp 1", "Temp 2 ()", "Temp 2","Temp 3 ()", "Temp 3"]
```

Can anyone help me out with this? What is the mistake in the code I wrote?

In **pandas** I tried this code and works

```
result_df["column1"]  = df["column1"].str.replace(" (gen. comb.)","",regex=False)
```

Can anyone tell me how I can strip string using **Pyspark?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using regex replace, you need to escape the brackets.

This should work:

```
result_df = df.withColumn('c_model_detail', regexp_replace('column1', ' \(gen\. comb\.\)', ''))
```

Comment: When i use this - I am left with `Temp 1.`

Comment: And what is your expected output?

Comment: The dot also should be removed. The output would be Temp 1

Comment: Changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now. @Robert Kossendey. Just one question - why is there space before the first \?  I was not putting space at first so I had wrong output

Comment: You want to delete " (gen. comb.)" and not "(gen. comb.)", so you need to add a space.